# How do you use existing C libraries with the Chrome Native Client?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app, google-nativeclient

I'm new to Chrome Application development and the Native Client/PNaCL pipeline. I'm a bit confused over the process of using existing C code/libraries in a chrome application. The FAQs and NaCL official docs suggest that using existing code is easy, and one of the advantages of developing Chrome applications.

However, there is also mention of nacl-ports, an official list of ported C libraries to be used in Native Client apps.

If I have some random C library I've used, what is the process for actually using it in my Chrome application? This question feels silly, but I'm quite confused over the process. Do I have to recompile the source with a NaCL compiler? Where in the SDK can I find this?

The FAQ also mentions that things like forks, file i/o is not allowed in the library, so I will have to rewrite any code that does these things, is that correct?

Bottomline: I have an existing C library. What is the process for using it correctly, and making calls to it, in a Chrome application?

Comment: I don't have URL at hand, but there's info on the web from Google about how to compile C for NaCL. You will have to compile your library that way. You can't use it in compiled form the way it is. Also, NaCL code can't make system calls to the OS. No file I/O, no fork/exec, no anything else like that. NaCL's purpose is to speed up processing and to make use of already-existing C code, not to give a Chrome App additional access to the underlying system.

Comment: @MarcRochkind Thank you for the information. I've found the info on compiling that you mention. Can you clarify the 'no file I/O' part? NaCL does extend the HTML5 storage API I thought, providing access to the local filesystem. So is it safe to say we can do file i/o, we just need to go through nacl_io and replace the original file read/write calls in the library source?

Comment: Sorry. I meant to say no file I/O via direct calls to the OS (Linux). Of course, Chrome API calls are OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that you'll have to recompile your library with a NaCl C compiler.

You may want to take a look at [naclports](https://code.google.com/p/naclports/): this repository contains ports of many common C libraries to Native Client. You can browse the source more easily [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/naclports/+/master).

As for File I/O, we often suggest using the nacl_io library when porting existing code. This provides a POSIX interface (e.g. fopen/fclose/fread, etc.) Many ported libraries require no modifications when using nacl_io.